# msgstore.db whatsapp android

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, internal-storage, data-recovery, huawei

Does the msgstore.db whatsapp file on android contain every msg every sent and received?
If so are voice notes digitally recoverable from the msgstore.db file?

Latest version whatsapp on android 9.

Regards

Comment: yes and no. every message is in this database. but no attachments

Comment: Are deleted voice notes recoverable at all using forensics? Thanks for answering.

Comment: we recently discussed that it is impossible to recover a deleted file from FBE https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/108420 but for FDE it's not completely hopeless

Comment: Is it only unrecoverable on a factory reset or normally deleted aswel? Thank you for the answers

Comment: some people claim this device is not encrypted. search for root exploit (if exist) https://forum.xda-developers.com/huawei-p20-pro/help/how-to-device-encryption-t3800297